# 2 queries on single connection? (classic ASP)

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I'm building a page to display a series of records but wanted to filter the results by location and display the resulting records under their own sub-heading.

All the records are in the one db table and there'll be a total of 2 queries.

SQL1 doest have any value there on my second HTML

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Top  Five Movies booking</title>
    <style>
    body {
        font: 100% "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    }
    table {
        /* The default setting is border-collapse: separate;. By changing separate to collapse as shown below, the space between each table cell is removed. */
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    caption {
        font-size: .9125em;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: .5em;
    }

    th,
    td {
        font-size: .875em;
        padding: .5em .75em;

    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid #000; 
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
      <% 
    'declare the variables 
    Dim Connection
    Dim ConnString
    Dim rs
    Dim SQL


    'define the connection string, specify database driver
    ConnString="Driver={SQL Server};Server=10.1.12.6;Database=VISTAIT;Uid=sa;Pwd=Cxx1234;"

'declare the SQL statement that will query the database
SQL = "SELECT  top 5   (OrderTH_strMovieName) as Top5HotFilms,Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) as DayOfCount,count( OrderTH_strMovieName)as filmoccurence FROM [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblOrderTicketHistory] where Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) >= (SELECT     DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) GROuP  BY OrderTH_strMovieName , Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112)ORDER BY  filmoccurence desc" 
SQL1 = "SELECT  top 10   (OrderTH_strMovieName) as Top5HotFilms,Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) as DayOfCount,count( OrderTH_strMovieName)as filmoccurence FROM [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblOrderTicketHistory] where Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) >= (SELECT     DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) GROuP  BY OrderTH_strMovieName , Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112)ORDER BY  filmoccurence desc" 

'create an instance of the ADO connection and rs objects
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Set rs1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

'Open the connection to the database
Connection.Open ConnString

'Open the rs object executing the SQL statement and return records 
rs.Open SQL, Connection



'first of all determine whether there are any records 
If rs.EOF Then 
Response.Write("No records returned.") 
Else 
'if there are records then loop through the fields 
Dim HTML, pHTML
  Dim field1, field2, field3, field4
  Set field1 = RS("Top5HotFilms")
  Set field2 = RS("DayOfCount")
  Set field3 = RS("filmoccurence")

  HTML = "<table CellPadding=0 CellSpacing=0 border=1><caption>Top  Five Movies booking</caption><TR><TD>Booking Date</td><TD>Day</td><TD>Occurence</td></TR>"&vbCrLf
   Do While Not rs.EOF
    pHTML = "<TR>"
    pHTML = pHTML & "<TD> " & field1 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML = pHTML & "<TD> " & field2 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML = pHTML & "<TD> " & field3 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML = pHTML & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
    HTML = HTML & pHTML
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
  HTML = HTML & "</table>" & vbCrLf

  Response.Write HTML
End If

rs1.Open SQL1, Connection
If rs1.EOF Then 
Response.Write("No records returned.") 
Else 
'if there are records then loop through the fields 
Dim HTML1, pHTML1
  Dim field5, field6, field7, field8
  Set field5 = RS1("Top5HotFilms")
  Set field6 = RS1("DayOfCount")
  Set field7 = RS1("filmoccurence")

  HTML1 = "<table CellPadding=0 CellSpacing=0 border=1><caption>Top  Ten Movies booking</caption><TR><TD>Booking Date</td><TD>Day</td><TD>Occurence</td></TR>"&vbCrLf
   Do While Not rs.EOF
    pHTML1 = "<TR>"
    pHTML1 = pHTML1 & "<TD> " & field5 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML1 = pHTML1 & "<TD> " & field6 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML1 = pHTML1 & "<TD> " & field7 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML1 = pHTML1 & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
    HTML1 = HTML1 & pHTML1
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
  HTML1 = HTML1 & "</table>" & vbCrLf

  Response.Write HTML1
End If




'close the connection and rs objects to free up resources
rs.Close
Set rs=nothing

rs1.Close
Set rs1=nothing

Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing

%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need to disconnect, you can run as many queries you like

Comment: So I define Dim SQL1 for next query? rs.Open SQL,SQL1 Connection ?

Comment: Can I have sample on the next query look alike and also do I need to rewrite the HTML for the next query

Comment: @EugeneJONG like Sami said u only need to disconnect from the database at the end. In between you can execute any number of sql queries...second query format will be according to your requirement..select,insert,delete what ever assign to the SQL string and execute like how u execute the first one..

Comment: @Sachu so how does my rs.open line look alike ?sorry I'm quite noob in asp

Comment: @EugeneJONG after your first loop u r closing `rs.close` and setting `rs = nothing`..then assing ur new query to sql and open rs as `rs.Open SQL,Connection`

Comment: @Sachu so it's rs.Open SQL1,Connection let said my next query I declare as SQL1?then follow by If rs.EOF then blah blah blah, right?

Comment: @EugeneJONG if u need to execute a query before closing rs then u need to create another record set as rs1 or something and a new string to hold the query as SQL1..else u can use same rs and SQL for the purpose..

Comment: roger that! thanks Sachu

Comment: @Sachu, could you help me verify my below pasted new code, the 2nd SQL doesnt respond any query result, anything wrong?

Comment: I have pasted my code here right now SQL1 doesnt seem to be output anything on page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL1 section has **`rs.movenext`** and **`Do While Not rs.EOF`** instead of **`rs1.movenext`** and **`Do While Not rs1.EOF`**

Below is the correct code for 2nd part

```
rs1.Open SQL1, Connection
If rs1.EOF Then 
 Response.Write("No records returned.") 
Else 
'if there are records then loop through the fields 
Dim HTML1, pHTML1
  Dim field5, field6, field7, field8

  HTML1 = "<table CellPadding=0 CellSpacing=0 border=1><caption>Top  Ten Movies booking</caption><TR><TD>Booking Date</td><TD>Day</td><TD>Occurence</td></TR>"&vbCrLf
   Do While Not rs1.EOF
    Set field5 = RS1("Top5HotFilms")
    Set field6 = RS1("DayOfCount")
    Set field7 = RS1("filmoccurence")
    pHTML1 = "<TR>"
    pHTML1 = pHTML1 & "<TD> " & field5 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML1 = pHTML1 & "<TD> " & field6 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML1 = pHTML1 & "<TD> " & field7 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML1 = pHTML1 & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
    HTML1 = HTML1 & pHTML1
    rs1.MoveNext
  Loop
  HTML1 = HTML1 & "</table>" & vbCrLf

  Response.Write HTML1
End If
```